# Nativescript: works geolocation inside a thread?

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation, nativescript

When I try to use Geolocation inside on a worker thread the program crash with next error

```
Error From Geolocation: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
JS:     com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
JS:     com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
JS:     com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
JS:     com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
JS:     com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
JS:     com...
```

But this not happen when i use geolocation inside from any component, example:

```
{
JS:   "android": {},
JS:   "latitude": 0,
JS:   "longitude": 0,
JS:   "altitude": 0,
JS:   "horizontalAccuracy": 0,
JS:   "verticalAccuracy": 0,
JS:   "speed": 0,
JS:   "direction": 0,
JS:   "timestamp": "2019-12-20T16:40:47.000Z"
JS: }
```

This is my thread

```
// app/worker.ts
import "globals";
import * as Geolocation from 'nativescript-geolocation';
import { Accuracy } from "tns-core-modules/ui/enums";

const context: Worker = self as any;

context.onmessage = function(msg) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentLocation({desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, maximumAge: 20000,timeout: 20000})
    .then(function(loc) {
             console.log(loc);
    }, function(e){              
             console.log("Error From Geolocation: " + e.message);
    });
};
```

I want to know if exists any way to use geolocation inside a thread

Comment: Did you obtain the location permissions from your main thread, before you could access the location on worker?

Comment: yes, all permissions are enabled